# React "document not defined" when including script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, document, eslint

I'm using ReactJS with Routing, ES6, Babel and ESLint. 
On click I want to add a CSS class using the classnames library, but I can't even use the `document.querySelector`. My whole application crashes and prints the error: `ReferenceError: document is not defined`

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default class Nav extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const sideNavToggleButton = document.querySelector('.js-toggle-menu');
        sideNavToggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.info('clicked');
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <header>
                <button role="tab" className="header__menu js-toggle-menu">Toggle nav menu</button>
                <h1 className="header__title">App Shell</h1>
            </header>
        );
    }
}
```

After some research I found out it might be my ESLint settings missing some environments, but after adding browser the application is still breaking.

```
module.exports = {
    'parser': 'babel-eslint',
    'plugins': [
        'react'
    ],
    'rules': {
        'indent': [2, 'tab'],
        'max-len': 0,
        'no-console': [2, { allow: ['info', 'error']}],
        'no-param-reassign': 0,
        'react/jsx-indent': [2, 'tab'],
        'react/jsx-indent-props': [2, 'tab'],
        'no-new': 0
    },
    'env': {
        'browser': true,
        'node': true
    }
};
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move this part of your code to the method `componentDidMount()`

```
const sideNavToggleButton = document.querySelector('.js-toggle-menu');
sideNavToggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.info('clicked');
});
```

Because `componentDidMount()` is the method that is called after the first rendering [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount). After rendering you can do any dom manipulation.

Comment: Yes fixed, so obvious

Comment: please make that as an accepted answer so that it may help others.